# which one is the unnacusative and which one is the unergative version of the following verbs

Tags: syntax, morphology

I'm having trouble answering the following syntax and morphology question:

Some languages allow identical looking verbs to behave like both unaccusatives AND unergatives or mark different types of intransitivity in the inflection. Have a look at these examples and determine which one is the unaccusative and which one is the unergative version. Explain your answer. Don’t worry too much about the abs/erg glosses, focus on the theta role you think the subject has.

**a)    Batsbi (Nakh language family)**

**So woze**
I.abs fell
I fell.

**As woze**

I.erg fell (my own fault)

I fell (my own fault)

**b)    Choctaw (Muskogean family).**

**sa-ttola-tok**
1.acc-fall-past

I fell.

**ittola-li-tok**

fall-1-past

I fell on purpose.

**c)    Lakhota (Siouan family)**

**Ma-hixpaye**
1sg-fall

I fell.

**wa-skate**

1sg.-play

I play.

How can I determine which one is the accusative and which one is the unergative version in the above examples a, b, and c ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't allow homework questions unless you have shown how you have tried to answer them yourself and shown what precisely you are having trouble with.

Comment: @curiousdannii man, I don't know how to answer that question. That's why I'm asking. All I can think about it is that the first verbs in a, b, and c are unaccusatives because their subjects are not agents executing the action indicated by the verbs, but that sounds way too simplistic to be the correct answer. Can you please give me some hints instead of trying to get my question closed?

Comment: Lots of questions are simple, and you may not need much more of an argument than that. I'd recommend you [edit] this to show which theta roles you'd identify for each noun phrase.